# Object returned as null when reading a file

Tags: arrays, vb.net, vb.net-2010

My task is to make a program that allows the user to input a question and an answer (true or false) in the same array, which if you were to read the file would look like:

```
"Question 1", "T"
```

It then needs to take the questions and randomly select five to display for output. My problem is that whenever I try to debug, it cannot read the file and instead returns an error.

```
        Private Sub Quiz(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnQuiz.Click
    If Viewed = True Then
        LoadData()
        RandomizeStrings()
        Duplicates()
        frmQuiz.Show()
        correct = 0
        answers = 0
        count = 0
    Else : MsgBox("You must view the slide show before you take the quiz!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "View Slide Show")
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub AddQuestion(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnQuestions.Click
    pass = "sample01"
    response = InputBox("Please enter the administrator password.", "Password")
    If response = pass Then
        Do
            FileOpen(1, "W:\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Culminating\assets\questions.txt", OpenMode.Append)
            question = InputBox("Enter new question (true or false format).", "New Question")
            If question = String.Empty Then
                Exit Do
                FileClose(1)
            End If
            answer = InputBox("Enter new answer (either 'T' or 'F').", "New Answer")
            answer = StrConv(answer, vbUpperCase)
            If answer = String.Empty Then
                question = String.Empty
                Exit Do
                FileClose(1)
            End If
            WriteLine(1, question, answer)
        Loop
    Else : MsgBox("Incorrect password. Please enter again.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Incorrect Password")
    End If
End Sub
Public Sub LoadData()
    FileOpen(1, "W:\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Culminating\assets\questions.txt", OpenMode.Input)
    Do While Not EOF(1)
        count = count + 1
        Input(1, question(count))
        Input(1, answer(count))
    Loop
    FileClose(1)
End Sub
Public Sub RandomizeStrings()
    Dim x As Object
    Randomize()
    For x = 1 To 5
        num(x) = Int((count - 1 + 1) * Rnd() + 1)
    Next x
End Sub
Public Sub Duplicates()
    Dim y As Object
    Dim x As Object
    For x = 1 To 4
        For y = (x + 1) To 5
            If num(x) = num(y) Then
                num(x) = Int((count - 1 + 1) * Rnd() + 1)
                x = 1
            End If
        Next y
    Next x
End Sub
```

My problems arise at this line in the *LoadData()* sub:

```
Input(1, question(count))
```

At this point, it gives me this error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I really don't know my way around this as I'm following the exemplar our teacher has given us and I don't want to go out on a limb and use a different method to complete this task (even though I think this is obsolete).

Comment: I'm betting that your teacher incremented `count` *after* reading the input, not before. Because you pre-increment, you end up off by one, missing the first value and trying to read one past. Of course, I am just guessing because I can't actually see the declaration for `question` or `answer`. I'm assuming they're global arrays?

Comment: @CodyGray actually no, this is more or less what was in the exemplar (which doesn't actually work). You would be correct in assuming they're global arrays.

Comment: The code does look strangely broken. Are you sure this is not a puzzle you're supposed to debug, rather than an example? :-) If `question` is really a global array, why does the `AddQuestion` sub-routine assign a single string to it in multiple places? I worry about your teacher's knowledge for other reasons, too, like using `FileOpen` to read data from a file. That's the old VB 6 way of doing it, pre-2000s. The modern VB.NET way is `System.IO.File` which has a lot fewer failure points.

Comment: @CodyGray no, this is actually something I'm supposed to make use of, not a puzzle. Also, I don't know, I might switch the `AddQuestion` subroutine from using input boxes to just plain textboxes and eliminate the use of the `question` and `answer` variables to see if that helps. I'm aware of the modern methods of file reading, however, I have to follow this example.